# Multipart upload in AWS S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have implemented multipart upload, to upload video files which are working fine, if the File uploads within 15 minutes.
What's process I am  doing: (this is working fine)

1. Create multipart upload Id
2. Take this multipart uplodeId and create multiple Aws s3 presigned URL .
3. Put request to Aws s3 with this presigned url and multiple chunks(small blob of big file)
4. Last is join together using completeMultipartUpload function of s3

One way to solve problem is to increase the time of presigned url from 15 minute to 30 or 40 minute

But client want:

1. Create a multipart upload Id
2. Take this multipart uplodeId and create **SINGLE** Aws s3 presigned URL.
3. Put **SINGLE** request to Aws s3 with this presigned URL,and put small size of e
4. Last is join together using completeMultipartUpload function of s3

here's the code  for preSigned URL which is BACKEND:(working fine)

```
const getMultipartPreSignedUrl: RequestHandler<{}> = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { fileName, uploadId, partNumber, fileType } = req.body
  const multipartParams = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileName,
    UploadId: uploadId,
    // ContentType: fileType,
  }
  const promises = []
  for (let index = 0; index < partNumber; index++) {
    promises.push(
      s3.getSignedUrlPromise("uploadPart", {
        ...multipartParams,
        PartNumber: index + 1,
      })
    )
  }
  const signedUrl = await Promise.all(promises)
  const partSignedUrlList = signedUrl.map((signedUrl, index) => {
    return {
      signedUrl: signedUrl,
      partNumber: index + 1,
    }
  })
  res.send({
    parts: partSignedUrlList,
  })
}
```

Here code which take presignedurl and Upload :(working fine)

```
 try {
      let res = await axios.post(`${url}/getUploadId`, { fileName: fileName })
      const uploadTempId = res.data.uploadId
      console.log(uploadTempId)
      setUploadId(uploadTempId)
      const chunkSize = uploadStatus.chunkSize * 1024 * 1024
      const chunkCount = Math.floor(fileSize / chunkSize) + 1

      setIsUploading({
        hasCompleted: false,
        isUploading: true,
      })
      setUploadStatus((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          partsUploaded: 0,
          totalParts: chunkCount,
        }
      })

      //   multipart url
      let multiUploadArray = []

      let getSignedUrlRes = await axios.post(`${url}/getUploadPart`, {
        fileName,
        partNumber: chunkCount,
        uploadId: uploadTempId.UploadId,
        fileType,
      })

      const allPartUploadPromises = []

      for (let uploadCount = 1; uploadCount < chunkCount + 1; uploadCount++) {
        let start = (uploadCount - 1) * chunkSize
        let end = uploadCount * chunkSize
        let fileBlob =
          uploadCount < chunkCount ? file.slice(start, end) : file.slice(start)

        let preSignedUrl = getSignedUrlRes.data.parts[uploadCount - 1].signedUrl

        allPartUploadPromises.push(
          axios
            .put(preSignedUrl, fileBlob, {})
            .then((response) => {
              let EtagHeader = response.headers["etag"]

              let uploadPartDetails = {
                ETag: EtagHeader,
                PartNumber: uploadCount,
              }

              multiUploadArray.push(uploadPartDetails)

              setUploadStatus((prev) => {
                return {
                  ...prev,
                  partsUploaded: prev.partsUploaded + 1,
                }
              })
            })
        )
      }
```

Now Change code that I am tring to achive the what client wants,but unable to execute:

Backend from presigned url for each chunk seperatly:

```
export const getSinglePartUploadUrl: RequestHandler<
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {
        fileName: string
        partNumber: number
        uploadId: string
      }
    > = async (req, res, next) => {
      const { fileName, partNumber, uploadId } = req.query
    
      const singedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("uploadPart", {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: fileName,
        UploadId: uploadId,
        PartNumber: +partNumber,
        Expires: 3000,
      })
    
      // return res.status(200).json({ signedUrl: singedUrl, partNumber: partNumber })
      return res.status(200).json(singedUrl)
     
    }
```

**Frontend code  which has error, which take presigned url** :

```
      let multiUploadArray = []


      const allPartUploadPromises = []

      for (let uploadCount = 1; uploadCount < chunkCount + 1; uploadCount++) {
        let start = (uploadCount - 1) * chunkSize
        let end = uploadCount * chunkSize
        let fileBlob =
          uploadCount < chunkCount ? file.slice(start, end) : file.slice(start)


        let signedUrl_Data = await axios.get(
          `${url}/getPartUploadUrl?fileName=${uniqueFileName}&partNumber=${uploadCount}&uploadId=${uploadTempId.UploadId}`
        )
        console.log(signedUrl_Data)
        delete axios.defaults.headers.put["Content-Type"]

        let data_Url = await axios.put(signedUrl_Data.data, fileBlob, {}).<--error 
        console.log(data_Url)


      }
      
      allPartUploadPromises.forEach((element) => {
        let x = Promise.resolve(element)
        console.log(x)
      })
```

Error I am getting is

```
<Error><Code>NoSuchUpload</Code><Message>The specified upload does not exist. The upload ID may be invalid, or the upload may have been aborted or completed <Error>
```

**Status code :404**

What I wanted to achive is to create presigned url for each chunck separately and uplode that , rather then creating multiple presigned url and uploding it one by one;
How I can achive this ?

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. It would be better if you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. This seems unnecessary.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't ever set uploadTempId, have you validated it's being set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have validated it is been set properly and going to the backend also.
Here is the code for it.


`let res = await axios.post(`${url}/getUploadId`, { fileName: fileName })


const uploadTempId = res.data.uploadId`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary what I want is that, no matter how slow the upload speed , file gets uploaded.  The problem I have also mentioned below is , let's a large file, takes more the 15 minutes to upload, till the time Presigned URL time has been expire. So I want not all presigned URLs generate at once,it should be generated one at a time